# Delete a html DIV with Python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to delete a div by its id in an html page using BeautifulSoup with Python, and I need also to add some attributes in a specific tag inside the same html page.

My code is like this:

**ORIGINAL HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="my_class">Div wanted with a new added attribute</div>
        <div id="to_delete">
            Parental div which I want to delete, that contains two other divs, one of which containing a table too.
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <table></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**WANTED FINAL HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="my_class" id="my_new_id">Wanted div, with a new attribute</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My python code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

html_data = open("index.html").read()

old_wanted_div = '''<div class="my_class"'''
new_wanted_div = '''<div class="my_class" id="my_new_id"'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
old_unwanted_div = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "to_delete"})
old_unwanted_div_str = '''{}'''.format(str(old_unwanted_div))
new_unwanted_div = ''' '''

reps = {old_wanted_div:new_wanted_div, old_unwanted_div_str:new_unwanted_div}

new_html = replace_all(html_data, reps)

f = open("index.html", "w")
f.write(new_html)
f.close()
```

Now, this code works to add an attribute, but does not delete the unwanted div, and I don't understand where is the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

BeautifulSoup allows you to replace the elements of HTML in place so you don't have to use string modifications.

To replace `to_delete` id, find that id in `soup`.

```
tg = soup.find_all(attrs={"id": "to_delete"})
print tg
out: 
     [<div id="to_delete">
        Parental div which I want to delete, that contains two other divs, one of which           containing a table too.
        <div></div>
        <div>
          <table></table>
        </div>
      </div>]
```

It returns a list of results. You can then replace the result by using `replace_with`.

```
tg[0].replace_with("")
```

This returns the replace result and at the same time replaces it in `soup`

```
print soup
out: <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
       <div class="my_class">Div wanted with a new added attribute</div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

You can similarly change `id` of first div after this removal --- Something like `soup.div.id = "new_id"`. Check this link for more on replace_with. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the trick

```
import re
newhtml = re.sub(re.compile('<div id="to_delete">.*body>',re.DOTALL),'</body>',oldhtml)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your help and reply!

I pursued what has been proposed by Sudeep Juvekar, being similar to the code already written, but thanks, bsoist!

I lost a bit of time to make it working.

I received an error:

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

solved with [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-November/614923.html) resource.

In essence, the working code appears to be this now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import shlex, subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# adding of a new attribute into the wanted DIV
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
old_html = open("index.html", "r")
old_data = old_html.read()
old_html.close()
old_wanted_div = '''<div class="my_class"'''
new_wanted_div = '''<div class="my_class" id="my_new_id"'''
replacements = {old_wanted_div:new_wanted_div}
new_data_1 = replace_all(old_data, replacements)
f = open("index.html", 'w')
f.write(new_data_1)
f.close()

# script to delete the DIV with id="to_delete", written in another python file
py_del_div = """from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
old_html = open("index.html", "r")
old_data = old_html.read()
old_html.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(old_data)
old_div_unwanted = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"id": "to_delete"})
new_div_unwanted = old_div_unwanted[0].replace_with("")
new_data_2 = str(soup)
new_file = open("index.html", "w")
new_file.write(new_data_2)
new_file.close()
exit()"""

py_script = open ("index.py", 'w')
py_script.write(py_del_div)
py_script.close()
py1_cmd = "pythonw ./index.py"
html_1 = shlex.split(py1_cmd)
subprocess1 = subprocess.Popen(html_1, shell=False)
subprocess1.wait()
subprocess1.terminate()

exit()
```

Unfortunately, at the moment, I had to split the python code, because the html is generated by a subprocess, and it seems that the substitutions start before then html has been generated, resulting in an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '. / Index.html'
```

I so thought to split the script, writing in another python script the part that removes the div, launched as subprocess ...

If anyone knows a cleaner way he is welcome.

Anyway thanks Sudeep Juvekar!

Greetings,
Riccardo